# An isomorphism between $\mathcal{L}(V)$ and $\mathcal{L}(V^{*})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I've found the exercise bellow in the book of Kenneth Hoffman and Ray Kunze called Linear Algebra:

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over the field $F$. Show that $T \to T^t$ is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{L}(V,V)$ onto $\mathcal{L}(V^{*},V^*)$.

I've proved that it is linear and injective, so it is an isomorphism ( $\dim \mathcal{L(V,V)} = \dim \mathcal{L}(V^{*},V^{*})$). But I would like to prove that it is surjective without using dimensions, that is, if $G \in \mathcal{L}(V^{*},V^{*})$, then there exists some $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,V)$  s.t $T^t=G$.

I would apreciate some hint about that.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $T'' = T$ (or at least there is some natural identification between the two?)

Comment: The problem with what you're trying to do is that it's impossible. For infinite-dimensional spaces, it's not necessarily true that the map $T \mapsto T^t$ is surjective.

Comment: My question is in the follow sense: If $\dim V< \infty$ then for all G in $\mathcal{L}(V^{*})$ there exist $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ s.t $T^t = G$. Of course that we need to use the dimension, but I don't wanna use that way above.

Comment: You can take a basis of $V$, look at the dual basis in $V^*$, take an element of $L(V^*,V^*)$, represent it by a matrix using the dual basis, transpose this matrix, and define the corresponding element of $L(V,V)$. This is bad because (1) you're explicitly using a basis and (2) the isomorphism $V \cong V^*$ only holds in finite dimensions and (3) the isomorphism in (2) is basis-dependent.

Comment: I'd be interesting to see if $T\mapsto T^t$ surjective implies $V$ finite-dimensional. But I don't think that's true either.

Comment: @leo It depends on whether you extend $V^*$ to the "continuous dual" or the "algebraic dual". For instance, if $V$ is a Hilbert space, then $T \mapsto T^*$ is surjective, but $T^*$ is defined on the continuous dual $V^* \cong V$. If $V^*$ is the algebraic dual and $V$ is infinite-dimensional, then I believe that $V^*$ is always of dimension strictly greater than that of $V$.

Comment: @Joãonani One nice approach might be to show that, in essence, $[T^t]^t = T$. From there, it follows that the transpose map is invertible (in particular is equal to its own inverse). Since an invertible linear map is an isomorphism, the conclusion follows.